# Does Ribbon cache Eureka entries?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

Does Ribbon cache Eureka entries (In order to avoid service lookup for every request) and if so how is it configured in Spring Cloud?  For example how would a Feign client like this configure time to live for the entries / refresh rates / etc:

```
@Bean
BookmarkClient bookmarkClient() {
  return loadBalance(BookmarkClient.class, "http://bookmark-service");
```

}

I have seen spring boot configuration entries like these:

```
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=1
eureka.instance.leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds=2
```

So in this case it seems like the cache would check with Eureka every second for changes and allow each entry cache entry to live for 2 seconds IIUC?  Also as far as spring-boot / spring cloud and Netflix REST clients go is there any difference for the configuration as far as access clients go (Feign/RestTemplate and various annotation combinations)?

For example I have seen `RestTemplate` configured like this:

```
   @Bean
   @LoadBalanced
   public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
   }
```

Would a Feign client use the same cache configuration settings that the above examples uses?  In other words is the configuration universal across all Spring cloud supported microservice rest clients?

Comment: It does, those settings are for the eureka client, not the ribbon client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the following changes to the Eureka client to fetch the registry during startup and cache it locally. After the initial fetch, the Eureka client will fetch delta:

```
eureka:
  client:
    fetchRegistry: true
```